# vagrant default configuration

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have configs that must always be present in Vagrantfile, when init is run, regardless of box.
For example when I run vagrant `init ubuntu/trusty64` or `vagrant init centos/7` this must be present in both Vagrantfiles:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.memory = 2048
 end

 config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   # obligatory provisioning goes here
 SHELL
```

Is there any way I can configure vagrant, so that when I run `vagrant init` this lines already be present in Vagrantfile?

Comment: Which line? `vb.memory = 2048`?

Comment: Probably your best option is to use a Ruby template and then write a script that generates your Vagrantfile from it.

Comment: @LipingHuang both. I need vm configuration, and provisioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you cant really change this behavior, unfortunately `vagrant init` does not propose an option to use your own Vagrantfile (that would be neat but not there). There are 2 templates (see https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/templates/commands/init) that can be used, the default one and a minimal one.

You're left with the following options:

1. overwrite the default template `Vagrantfile.erb`

search the file in your system (on mac it should be somewhere in `/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.1/templates/commands/init/Vagrantfile.erb` depending your version) and change it to what you need.

2. You can have a global `Vagrantfile` under the `.vagrant.d` directory that will be applied to all your Vagrantfiles. See *LOAD ORDER AND MERGING*
   in [vagrantfile documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/).
3. Write a plugin with a new command to create the Vagrantfile. that is probably overkill though

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with second option. 
Maybe someone will find it helpful:
I've been confused since I added some code to `~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile` but it didnt changed the generated Vagrantfile after `vagrant init`. But nevertheless all changes took affect after `vagrant up`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/environmental-variables.html#vagrant_default_template

put `export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE=~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile.erb` in ~/.bash_profile

```
touch ~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile.erb
```

with content

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "main"
  config.vm.box = "<%= box_name %>"
  <% if box_version -%>
  config.vm.box_version = "<%= box_version %>"
  <% end -%>
  <% if box_url -%>
  config.vm.box_url = "<%= box_url %>"
  <% end -%>
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "4096"
    vb.cpus = 4
  end
end
```

then `source ~/.bash_profile`

`vagrant init ubuntu/bionic64`

It works great!